# Angular 5: 2 imported items with forRoot can't exist together in the app.module.ts file

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a problem in my project, in the app.module.ts file, i have imported the item **HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(...)** to mock the test result, it worked well. Then i imported the item: **TranslateModule.forRoot(...)** for the translation use, then i got an error:

*ERROR AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js?[sm]:1 Error: [object: Object] at viewWrapperdDebugError at call.....*

I tried to comment the first item(HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(...)), that resolve the problem, i can get the translated words with TranslateModule.
But can i use the two items at the same time? Can you tell me why i have this error?

Here is the code:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ToasterModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ImageZoomModule,
    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns silmulated server response
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemorySearchDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false}
    ),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    HttpClientModule,


    QuillEditorModule,
    NgxGalleryModule


  ],
  providers: [SearchService,
    FormBuilder,
    ConsultService,
    NavigationService,
    NotificationService,
    FinaliseService,
    RetryService,
    JsonDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Thank you